# Python/SQLITE - OperationalError: no such module: RTREE

Tags: python, sqlite

I had a python script, which up until last week was operating fine now I receive the error:  `OperationalError: no such module: RTREE`

The code is here :

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_db_link)

#Update dates and fields from Julian to Gregorian + 10.5 hours
conn.execute('ALTER TABLE SQLITE_TABLE ADD COLUMN Date_Received_G DATE')
conn.execute('UPDATE SQLITE_TABLE SET Date_Received_G = date(Date_Received, "localtime")')
```

The script simply adds a new date field to the database and then updates it with the date updated to local time (from UTS Julian Date it is downloaded as)

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This happened to me too, a script working for years suddenly stopped working when I upgraded to ArcGIS 10.7. I now see looking back through my files that I patched the sqlite.dll in 2018 with a better version direct from the sqlite [download site](https://sqlite.org/download.html) instead of the bundled DLL with the Esri 10.6 install which did not enable extensions or have the rtree extension included. That appears to coincide with Esri's change to the Anaconda distribution for ArcGISPro but must have also been switched for ArcMap.
I also use the much larger mod_spatialite.dll extension which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some virtual table in this database is using the [R-tree module](https://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html), and the version of the SQLite library used by your Python is not compiled with that.

You can access this database only with an SQLite library that has R-tree support.